Como contener hyperlink en un solo elemento
tengo este código que hace que al hacer clic sobre el texto, se copie la url del sitio. Pero resulta, que todo lo que sigue después de ese texto con link, queda para hacer clic con el mismo hyperlink. No se si me explico... o sea, que lo que está después del texto con link, queda también para hacer clic.


<span class="copiar-url" title="<?php echo $we['lang']['edit'];?>">
<li href="<?php echo We_SeoLink('index.php?link1=setting&user=' . $we['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting') ?>" data-ajax="?link1=setting&user=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting'; ?>"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-link-45deg" viewBox="0 0 14 14"> <path d="M4.715 6.542 3.343 7.914a3 3 0 1 0 4.243 4.243l1.828-1.829A3 3 0 0 0 8.586 5.5L8 6.086a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-.154.199 2 2 0 0 1 .861 3.337L6.88 11.45a2 2 0 1 1-2.83-2.83l.793-.792a4.018 4.018 0 0 1-.128-1.287z"/> <path d="M6.586 4.672A3 3 0 0 0 7.414 9.5l.775-.776a2 2 0 0 1-.896-3.346L9.12 3.55a2 2 0 1 1 2.83 2.83l-.793.792c.112.42.155.855.128 1.287l1.372-1.372a3 3 0 1 0-4.243-4.243L6.586 4.672z"/> </svg>  <a class="getlink" href="javascript:getlink();">Copiar enlace</li>
</span>
        </ul>
        
        <?php if(!empty($we['page_profile']['page_description'])) {  ?>
            <div class="page-margin wow_content">
                <div class="we_page_hdng profile_hdng_side pag_neg_padd">
                    <div class="we_page_hdng_innr"><?php echo $we['lang']['about']; ?></div>
                </div>
                <p class="page-margin mt-0"><?php echo $we['page_profile']['page_description']?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>



Lo que esta como ['page_description'] que es la descripcion de la pagina, queda marcado como para hacer click. No se como hacer para que solo quede el Copiar enlace con enlace para hacer click. Como puedo indicarle que es solo hasta ahi, y que no tenga efecto en ['page_description']

A primera vista, pareciera ser que simplemente olvidaste cerrar el tag <a> con un </a>. Me refiero:


<li href="<?php echo We_SeoLink('index.php?link1=setting&user=' . $we['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting') ?>" data-ajax="?link1=setting&user=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting'; ?>"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-link-45deg" viewBox="0 0 14 14"> <path d="M4.715 6.542 3.343 7.914a3 3 0 1 0 4.243 4.243l1.828-1.829A3 3 0 0 0 8.586 5.5L8 6.086a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-.154.199 2 2 0 0 1 .861 3.337L6.88 11.45a2 2 0 1 1-2.83-2.83l.793-.792a4.018 4.018 0 0 1-.128-1.287z"/> <path d="M6.586 4.672A3 3 0 0 0 7.414 9.5l.775-.776a2 2 0 0 1-.896-3.346L9.12 3.55a2 2 0 1 1 2.83 2.83l-.793.792c.112.42.155.855.128 1.287l1.372-1.372a3 3 0 1 0-4.243-4.243L6.586 4.672z"/> </svg>  <a class="getlink" href="javascript:getlink();">Copiar enlace</li>
<p>Otro elemento que no debería estar en el link</p>



Pero si se cierra correctamente el tag:


<li href="<?php echo We_SeoLink('index.php?link1=setting&user=' . $we['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting') ?>" data-ajax="?link1=setting&user=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting'; ?>"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-link-45deg" viewBox="0 0 14 14"> <path d="M4.715 6.542 3.343 7.914a3 3 0 1 0 4.243 4.243l1.828-1.829A3 3 0 0 0 8.586 5.5L8 6.086a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-.154.199 2 2 0 0 1 .861 3.337L6.88 11.45a2 2 0 1 1-2.83-2.83l.793-.792a4.018 4.018 0 0 1-.128-1.287z"/> <path d="M6.586 4.672A3 3 0 0 0 7.414 9.5l.775-.776a2 2 0 0 1-.896-3.346L9.12 3.55a2 2 0 1 1 2.83 2.83l-.793.792c.112.42.155.855.128 1.287l1.372-1.372a3 3 0 1 0-4.243-4.243L6.586 4.672z"/> </svg>  <a class="getlink" href="javascript:getlink();">Copiar enlace</a></li>
    <p>Otro elemento que no debería estar en el link</p>



Si revisas el HTML generado con las DevTools de tu navegador, notarás que el tag se termina cerrando automáticamente, pero ya que el navegador no sabe donde querías cerrar el tag intenta tomar todos los elementos que podrían haber estado dentro del tag. Esto resulta en todos los elementos delante del tag <a> teniendo su propio link.

Vicente, lo cerre con  y funciono :) No me di cuenta, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos!
